# JS Function when rendering ListView Webpart

Tags: 2013

I implemented a JS-Script in order to fill an empty column in a Listview Webpart. However, Re-Rendering (Change sorting, page up/down) the Webpart leeds to disabling the JS-Script.

How can I rerun the JS Script in case of Re-Rendering?

Thanks in advance, regards! Tommy

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial helped to solve the Problem...

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013/